# How to forcibly remove the resource created by the broken module?

Tags: terraform, terraform-module

I've created few [`dns_cname_record` resources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/dns/r/dns_cname_record.html), however [Terraform DNS provider](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-dns) started to throw the errors like:

> Error: update server is not set

I've created the [bug report](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-dns/issues/83) for it, as it prevents me from running any Terraform command. The error is basically shown on every Terraform command, including `plan`.

Now I want to clean up and get rid of this DNS module completely, and all references to it. So I've removed all my `dns_cname_record` resources from all `.tf` files. However there are some still resources stored in a state file which I want to get rid of.

```
$  terraform show | grep -w dns_cname_record
# dns_cname_record.foo-example: 
resource "dns_cname_record" "foo-example" {
# dns_cname_record.bar-example: 
resource "dns_cname_record" "bar-example" {
```

So I've tried to destroy it with force without refreshing state, but it failed as well:

```
$ TF_LOG=trace terraform destroy -target=dns_cname_record.foo-example -force -refresh=false
...
[TRACE] <root>: eval: *terraform.EvalIf
[TRACE] <root>: eval: *terraform.EvalApplyProvisioners
[TRACE] <root>: eval: *terraform.EvalIf
[TRACE] <root>: eval: *terraform.EvalIf
[TRACE] <root>: eval: *terraform.EvalApply
[DEBUG] dns_cname_record.foo-example: applying the planned Delete change
[TRACE] GRPCProvider: ApplyResourceChange
[DEBUG] dns_cname_record.foo-example: apply errored, but we're indicating that via the Error pointer rather than returning it: update server is not set
[TRACE] <root>: eval: *terraform.EvalWriteState
[TRACE] EvalWriteState: writing current state object for dns_cname_record.foo-example
[TRACE] <root>: eval: *terraform.EvalApplyPost
[ERROR] <root>: eval: *terraform.EvalApplyPost, err: update server is not set
[ERROR] <root>: eval: *terraform.EvalSequence, err: update server is not set
[ERROR] <root>: eval: *terraform.EvalOpFilter, err: update server is not set
[TRACE] [walkDestroy] Exiting eval tree: dns_cname_record.foo-example (destroy)
[TRACE] vertex "dns_cname_record.foo-example (destroy)": visit complete
[TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "dns_cname_record.foo-example (clean up state)" errored, so skipping
[TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "provider.dns (close)" errored, so skipping
[TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "meta.count-boundary (EachMode fixup)" errored, so skipping
[TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "root" errored, so skipping

Error: update server is not set

Releasing state lock. This may take a few moments...
[DEBUG] plugin: plugin process exited: path=~/.terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-dns_v2.1.1_x4 pid=76229
[DEBUG] plugin: plugin exited
```

and at the end, it doesn't remove invalid entry, because of [the error](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-dns/search?q=%22update+server+is+not+set%22&unscoped_q=%22update+server+is+not+set%22).

I've also tried to remove `terraform-provider-dns_v2.1.1_x4` binary module file, but `teraform plan` complains about it, and `terraform init` downloads it again, and the problem repeats.

Is there any higher power command than `destroy -force -refresh=false` to get rid of the invalid entries from the state file which breaking local setup? Or I need to edit the state file manually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The workaround is to pull the current state file, edit it and use it as a base line. For example:

```
$ terraform state pull > terraform.tfstate
$ vim terraform.tfstate # Carefully remove invalid entries.
$ python -mjson.tool terraform.tfstate # Validate JSON.
```

<sup>Note: In Vim, placing cursor on the opening bracket, hitting <kbd>d%</kbd> will remove the whole group.</sup>

Then plan and apply:

```
$ terraform plan -state=terraform.tfstate -refresh=false
$ terraform apply -state=terraform.tfstate -refresh=false
```

---

Alternatively, pull, edit and push your local state file into remote state:

```
$ terraform state pull > terraform.tfstate
$ vim terraform.tfstate # Remove invalid entries and increase the serial value.
$ terraform state push terraform.tfstate
```

---

For Azure, it's better to use [`terraform-provider-azurerm`](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm) instead of general DNS provider ([`terraform-provider-dns`](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-dns)).